# Проксирование на базе Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, proxy, nuxt.js

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём фишка?

Вроде бы всё работает (правда не так, как мне хотелось бы), но меня никак не отпускает один момент:

Я использую [Nuxt.js](https://ru.nuxtjs.org/). В файле конфига прописала следующее:

***nuxt.config.ts***

```
axios: {
  proxy: true
},
proxy: {
  "/api": {
    target: "https://example.com/api",
    pathRewrite: { "^/api": "" }
  }
}
```

У меня по данному адресу: `https://example.com/api` (естественно он изменён) выдаётся простейший JSON. Как только обращаюсь с localhost, то выдаётся такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если я при обращении к URL добавляю в конце "`/`" (слэш), вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка пропадает. Почему так?

Comment: а роуты какой вид имеют? С "/" на конце?

Comment: @Дмытрык `Nuxt.js` [сам генерирует](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/) маршруты на основе того, что лежит в папке `pages`. Но на сколько я поняла там без "`/`" получается.